# How to create mobile web and transaction on java

Tags: java, mysql, mobile

I'm working in database mysql.
I want to know how to create database connection through mysql.
Because when I make connections there is a error.
thanks..

Comment: What error do you get? What did you try? What exactly are you trying to to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to connect to MySql database with Java (JDBC)
http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html

Like @npinti said, what's the error message you are getting?